# nokogiri doc.xpath() problem

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

when looping through many web pages and calling something simple like below

```
manyhtmlpages.each do |page|

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page) 

puts doc.xpath("/html/body/h2[1]","/html/body/a[1]").to_s

end
```

i observe that memory consumption continually goes up until the script terminates due to running out of memory.

when i remove the doc.xpath bit, this error above is not experienced.

Comment: How many pages is it? Does it happen if you examine only a few? Is the consumption linear to the amount of pages?

Comment: it happens with around a few thousand html unique pages. and more.

Comment: Changing your username doesn't make it any less annoying that you're posting the same question over and over.

Comment: sorry nobody knew the answer earlier and my account keeps getting deleted when i close browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root of the problem lies in that the code is not garbage collected until both page and doc leaves the scope (correct me if I'm wrong).

A similar problem is described [here](http://xaop.com/blog/2008/04/01/libxml-ruby-memory-leaks/).
This is a problem with libxml-ruby, but as far as I know, nokogiri actually build on libxml.

I'm sorry, but I don't know the exact details about this problem. It's just to point you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you i think this is the right direction.... i am going to try force garbage collection with gc.start